# Demultiplexing RTP video streams in Gstreamer1.0

Tags: video, udp, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtp

I am trying to stream two video streams (H264) over RTP to the client side with GStreamer1.0. The server does encoding and then RTP multiplexing and the client does RTP demultiplexing and then decoding. Both pipelines run OK, but I don't see anything rendered on the client side (xvimagesink windows do not show).

Server:

```
gst-launch-1.0 \  
    rtpmux name=mux ! udpsink host=157.54.158.88 port=5000 \  
    videotestsrc pattern=snow ! 'video/x-raw, format=I420, width=1920, height=1080' ! \  
    omxh264enc ! 'video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream' ! h264parse ! \  
    rtph264pay config-interval=1 ! mux.sink_0 \  
    videotestsrc pattern=snow ! 'video/x-raw, format=I420, width=1920, height=1080' ! \  
    omxh264enc ! 'video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream' ! h264parse ! \  
    rtph264pay config-interval=1 ! mux.sink_1
```

Client:

```
gst-launch-1.0 \  
    udpsrc port=5000 ! 'application/x-rtp, encoding-name=H264, payload=96' ! \  
    rtpptdemux name=demux ! \  
    queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! \  
    videoscale ! video/x-raw, width=960, height=540 ! \  
    xvimagesink sync=false demux. ! \  
    queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! \  
    videoscale ! video/x-raw, width=960, height=540 ! xvimagesink sync=false
```

Can anyone tell what's wrong with these scripts? Both sides are running, but no videos are rendered on the client side.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any chance that a firewall is blocking your UDP packets? Have you tried host=127.0.0.1? Do you see incoming activity with a tcpdump trace?